# What is the difference between GAS ( Generalized Autoregressive Score) model and a GARCH?

Tags: forecasting, garch, winsorizing, trimmed-mean

I am trying to analyze some data about Brent Oil volatility. So far I have managed to fit a GARCH(1,1) model and an EGARCH. However, someone has recommended to use a GAS model, Generalized Autoregressive Score model, [GAS Model webpage](http://www.gasmodel.com/). But the problem is that I don't see clear when I should use this model, why and what's the difference with a GARCH.

I'd really appreciate if you could give some insight about it!!

Answer (score 2):

A GARCH model is a special case of a GAS volatility model when the measurement density is normal. When the measurement density is non-normal, the corresponding score that drives the model will be different. For example, using a t-distribution leads to 'trimming' of heavy-tailed observations, whereas using a GED distribution leads to 'Winsorization'. The normal score - aka the GARCH score- reacts linearly with respect to the residuals so does not have a similar robustness property.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of rjt90 is correct but since I'm working on these models, I thought I expand on it.

**Score-driven framework**
In the class of score-driven models (or GAS models), the time-varying parameter $\alpha_t$ is updated over time using an autoregressive updating function based on the score of the conditional observation probability density function, see

[Creal, D. D., S. J. Koopman, and A. Lucas (2013). Generalized autoregressive score models with applications. Journal of Applied Econometrics 28(5), 777--795](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jae.1279)

For a GAS(1,1) model, the updating function for $\alpha_t$ is given by
$$
\alpha_{t+1} = \omega + \beta \alpha_{t} + \kappa s_{t}, 
$$
where $\omega$ is a constant, $\beta$ and $\kappa$ are fixed coefficients and $s_t$ is the scaled score function which is the driving force behind the updating equation.

The definition of $s_t$ is
$$
\qquad s_t = S_t \cdot \nabla_t, \qquad \nabla_t = \frac{\partial \, \log \, p(y_t | \alpha_t)}{\partial \alpha_t}, \qquad t = 1,\ldots,T,
$$
where $\nabla_{t}$ is the score (first derivative wrt $\alpha_t$) of the density $p(y_t | \alpha_t)$ of the observed time series.
To introduce further flexibility in the model, the score $\nabla_{t}$ can be scaled by $S_t$.
A common choices for $S_t$ is the inverse of the Fisher information.

**The link with GARCH models**
Consider the time-varying variance model
$$
y_t = \mu + \varepsilon_t, \qquad \varepsilon_t \sim NID(0, \alpha_t),
$$
for $t = 1,\ldots,T$ and where NID means Normally Independently Distributed. After setting $\mu = 0$ for notational convenience, we have the predictive logdensity
$$
\ell_t = -\frac{1}{2} \, \text{log} \, 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} \, \text{log} \, \alpha_t - \frac{y_t^2}{2 \alpha_t}.
$$
Following the score-driven framework, we obtain
\begin{align}\nonumber
\nabla_t &= \frac{1}{2 \alpha_t^2} \, y_t^2 - \frac{1}{2 \alpha_t} ,\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \alpha_t^2} (y_t^2 - \alpha_t)\nonumber.
\end{align}
Furthermore, we have $S_t = 2 \alpha_t^2$ and $s_t = y_t^2 - \alpha_t$.
This means that the score updating becomes
$$
\alpha_{t+1} = \omega + \beta \alpha_t + \kappa (y_t^2 - \alpha_t),
$$
and hence score updating implies the GARCH(1,1) model
$$
\alpha_{t+1} = \omega + \phi \alpha_t + \kappa^* y_t^2,
$$
where $\phi = \beta - \kappa$ and $\kappa^* \equiv \kappa$.
If we set $\kappa = \beta$, we obtain the ARCH(1) model. The above is valid for higher lag orders as well which means that the score-driven framework encompasses the GARCH(p,q) model.

If we change the density $p(y_t | \alpha_t)$ we obtain a different model (with possibly very attractive properties) and hence the score-driven framework is very flexible.
An often better fitting distribution for volatility is the Student *t* and even 'exotic' distributions like the Exponential Generalized Beta II easily fit in the score-driven framework.

Time series software that uses the score-driven methodology is available for free from https://timeserieslab.com and I am one of the developers.